# mulitple repositories in a single view

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I read some of the questions on creating a view that contains multiple repositories but I can't seem to get the correct combination to get it to work.

I 3 repositories that connect to three different tables in a SQL database.  I have controllers and viewmodels for each that display the information correctly.  I can't seem to get partial views to work.  When I create a view and than try to use the partialview in the view I receive error that the model does not contain the repository.  I am wondering if I need to have only one file with 3 repository classes in it.

I have:
DomainPlayerRepository.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Domain.Games;

namespace Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface DomainPlayerRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Player> Player { get; }
    }

}
```

DomainGameRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Domain.Games;

namespace Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface DomainGameRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Game> Game { get; }
    }
}
```

GamePartialView.cshtml

```
@model Domain.Games.Game

<div class="Game">
    @Model.Date   @Model.NumPlayers @Model.PotMoney

</div>
```

List.cshtml (for Player)

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Games.Player>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Players";
}

<h2>Player</h2>

@foreach (var p in Model) 
{
    <div class ="player">
       <h3>@p.FName  @p.LName Handicap @p.Handicap.ToString()</h3>
    </div>

}

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <div class ="game">
      @Html.Partial("GamePartialView", p)
    </div>

}
```

I have also been trying to get a viewmodel with both my repositories in it but that is not working yet.

MultiRepositoryViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Domain.Games;

namespace WebUI.Models
{
    public class MultiRepositoryViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Player> Player { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Game> Game { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get? what do you mean with "is not working"?

Comment: The errors is that the model "Domain.Games.Player does not contain Game" (shortened version).  Which correct, I have a different Model in my PartialView which is "Domain.Games.Game".  I think it may have something to do with me not using an abstract in my controller. Not sure exactly what that is but I am trying "ActionResult" instead of "ViewResult" to if that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the model of the view to the ViewModel and use the properties you've defined

```
@model WebUI.Models.MultiRepositoryViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Players";
}

<h2>Player</h2>

@foreach (var p in Model.Player) 
{
    <div class ="player">
       <h3>@p.FName  @p.LName Handicap @p.Handicap.ToString()</h3>
    </div>
}

@foreach (var p in Model.Game)
{
    <div class ="game">
       @Html.Partial("GamePartialView", p)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did not even think to change the model statement.  I now get a different error,  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Domain.Games.Player]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebUI.Models.MultiRepositoryViewModel'. I will try figure out why the compiler is getting confused.

Comment: When you call the `View(model)` method in your controller, you have to pass a new instance of the `MultiRepositoryViewModel` instead of passing the `DbSet<Player>` :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to do that.  If I create a new instance of MultiRepositoryView the values in it are NULL.  Such as "var MultiRepositoryView = new MutliRepositoryView; return View(MultiRepositoryView); in my Player Controller List() method. BTW thanks for the help.

Comment: you have to assign the Player and Game properties with the values from your repositories

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I finally have it displaying 2 different repositories.  I had to step back and get my MultiRepsoitoryView working and than modified that to get the GamePartialView working.